# Error when using setState inside a ReactJS API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm using an API called 'react-svg', it allows me to inject SVG file into the DOM and also have a copy of the SVG element so I can use it later.

This API has a functionality called 'afterInjection', it's basically a function called after injecting the SVG file, inside that function I tried to update the component state and I got an error :

**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

```
import { ReactSVG } from 'react-svg';
import Sketch from '../sketch/Sketch';
import './ImageUploader.scss';
import Complex from 'complex.js';


class ImageUploader extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      pointsArray : [],
      fileURL : null,
      file: null
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      file : event.target.files[0],
      fileURL: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    })

  }

  add_svg = () => {
    if (this.state.fileURL !== null) {
      return (
        <ReactSVG
          src={this.state.file.name}
          afterInjection={(error, svg) => {
            if (error) {
              console.error(error)
              return
            }

            this.convert_path( svg.children[0].children[0] );

          }}
        />
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  convert_path = path => {
    let points = [];
    const length = path.getTotalLength();
    const step = length / 100;
    for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i -= step) {
      // console.log(path.getPointAtLength(i));
      points.push( new Complex( path.getPointAtLength(i).x, path.getPointAtLength(i).y)  );
    }

    this.setState({ pointsArray : points });

  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div >

        <div className="upload_sketch_container">

          <div className="input_container">
            <input type="file" id="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="file">Upload SVG file</label>
          </div>

          <div className="image_sketch_container">

            <div className="image_container" >
              {this.add_svg()}
            </div>

            <div className="sketch_container">
              <Sketch data={this.state.pointsArray} />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageUploader;
```

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: @ZombieChowder in this line  `this.setState({ pointsArray : points }); `

Comment: `React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` Well how many SVG points are you pushing and trying to update the state? Maybe try to to push everything to the array and **then** update the state?

Comment: @ZombieChowder It's exactly what I'm doing. Pushing everything then updating state.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted is exactly correct. You've created an infinite loop in your component. You render your component, which calls `add_svg`, which calls `convert_path`, which updates state, which triggers a rerender, which calls `add_svg`, etc. If you coment out the call to `this.convert_path` in `add_svg`, your infinite loop problem will vanish.

Comment: Totally true ! How did I miss that !
But what do you suggest as a solution ?

Comment: If you're looking to trigger a function call once (or conditionally), use the lifecycle hook methods that React provides, e.g. `componentDidMount`, etc.